# typescript package is installed correctly with npm but vs code cannot find it

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

I am developing a very simple npm package (type-exception) with TypeScript. My tests runs without errors and I was able to publish on NPM and even I can install it in another project (project B); but when I import it as reference, VS Code throw me an Exception "cannot find 'type-exception' module" (on project B)

I have installed another package on project B without errores, so I think my package that I released on NPM has some issue, but I cannot figure what is.

Basically, I made two classes and in the main.ts file export them like this:

```
export { nameof } from "./reflection-helper";
export { TypeException } from "./type-exception";
```

My folder project structure of type-exception project is like this:

```
src
+-src
|--index.ts
|--reflection-helper.ts
|--type-exception.ts
|-test
|-node_modules
+-lib
|--src
|--test
```

The source code of "type-exception" project can be found [here](https://github.com/vvenegasv/type-exception)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> throw me an Exception "cannot find 'type-exception' module" (on project B)

This is a runtime exception. This is because your project's `main` is not pointing a file : https://github.com/vvenegasv/type-exception/blob/f7ec4f63a4cb129e73ed2c4592014adb7b363913/src/package.json#L5

It is

```
"main": "type-exception",
```

Should be like

```
"main": "./lib/something/type-exception",
```

Comment: Need I to put the file extension? Like this? "main": "./lib/src/type-exception.js"

Comment: Ok, I fix it changing this line to "main": "./src/index.ts". Thanks